# I need an entire row copied to a new sheet if value of certain column on Sheet 1 = x

Tags: vba, excel

We are currently using a shared excel workbook to track inventory in a small business. Sheet "Inventory List" lists each product with price, vendor, cost, etc. There is also a column we have created to mark an "x" if we need to order the product. Therefore, if there is an "x" in that column (column E) that whole row would then be copied and pasted into a new sheet. On this new sheet I would like them to be organized by vendor which is column P on Inventory List. Please let me know if you can help. Thank you.

Comment: Please add details on what you've already tried (including relevant code) as well as the results of those efforts, and why the results were not good enough, as this will help us help you with a good solution. (also, a search of SO will probably yield many people asking similar questions :) )

Comment: and to give you a push in the right direction: `Cells.find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row` will find the number of rows in a sheet. use a for loop to process each row, and use: `cells(i, col).value ' where i is the loop index, and col is the column with the x in it` to check the value of the cell. then: `cells(i,col)entireRow.copy Destination:= Sheet.Range(x,y)` will copy / paste a row :)

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you run the macro from the sheet with data and there already exists a sheet called **New Sheet**

```
Sub dural()
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Set s1 = ActiveSheet
Set s2 = Sheets("New Sheet")
Dim K As Long, N As Long, i As Long

K = 1
N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To N
    With Cells(i, "E")
        If .Value = "x" Then
            .EntireRow.Copy s2.Cells(K, 1)
            K = K + 1
        End If
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```